# Does channel stop sending or receiving data on coroutine scope cancellation?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to kotlin coroutine, i am using `Channel` in my coroutine, I need to know whether the channel created in the particular scope will get cancelled once the scope get cancelled.

> will the channels acts as a children in that scope?

**Example**

```
class TestingChannel {

    val channel = Channel<String>(Channel.BUFFERED)

    suspend fun start() {
        coroutineScope {
            awaitAll(
                async { startSendingData() },
                async { startReceiveData() }
            )
        }
    }

    suspend fun startSendingData() {
        channel.send("some_data")
    }

    suspend fun startReceiveData() {
        for (data in channel) {
            print(data)
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel : ViewModel() {

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            TestingChannel().start()
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        /**
         * on Clearing the viewmodel scope, will my channel in the that scope stop sending or receiving data
         */
    }
}
```

In the above code i don't use `produce` function since it is in experimental state.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu you can see that even after cancelling the ```Job```, the channel is able to ```send``` or ```receive``` whereas the ```isClosedForReceive``` & ```isClosedForSend``` returning false.

Comment: Ya it does not get cancelled if i add a delay after join it does sends the strings, the coroutine which is starting (calling `start()`) will gonna get cancelled in your case. You can override the job of the parent scope before launching it to make it unaffected by the cancellation.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu can it be cancelled while catching cancellation exception?

Comment: if you make the coroutine which call `start` non cancellable then the sender won't stop. Check https://pl.kotl.in/Cs0BW2EE- (non cancellable) https://pl.kotl.in/NyT8OX2lH (cancellable)

Comment: Channel never participates in the scope of whom it was created all things happen with the sender and receivers, They are what going to be cancelled. To cancel a channel only close() is what makes it closed.